# Typescript generic type for anything but a function

Tags: typescript

`structuredClone` or `lodash.cloneDeep` cannot clone functions.

Is there a way to exclude `Function` type from generic?

I tried `object: Exclude<T, {[key: string|number|symbol]: any, apply: any, call: any}>` and
`object: Exclude<T, Function>`, both will return a type error when the object is passed in as `this` of a class.

```
function cloneAnythingButFunction1<T>(object: Exclude<T, {[key: string|number|symbol]: any, apply: any, call: any}>): T{
    return structuredClone(object)}

function cloneAnythingButFunction2<T>(object: Exclude<T, Function>): T{
    return structuredClone(object)
}

// Expect error:
cloneAnythingButFunction1(cloneAnythingButFunction1)
cloneAnythingButFunction2(cloneAnythingButFunction2)

// Expect no error:
class Test{
    clone1(){
        return cloneAnythingButFunction1(this) // error
    }
    clone2(){
        return cloneAnythingButFunction2(this) // error
    }
}
const test = new Test()
cloneAnythingButFunction1(test)
cloneAnythingButFunction2(test)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221003&ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBvAUNT1QHsB28AjABQCU6Wl0ATvEgK7V7Yj7wCCeAnkgBYCWeAOYAhekgBi9PMCT98JPvwikMWAL5rMuAgCYyFKploMmLNpx4DhYydNny8+pSq3RNmtADN7c-OYJLJRtxKRk-PEIAHlgAPmIcACMAK3hZAC5oAFEAD1B6ABN4GIAaaBQAbQBreC5M5GpBIQAfPHoAW0T4amaILk6cEABdTLBuMrAAB0mQOugxrjLgMBAQUe51WNJM2ENjOkZmBvpZRngCgGFWAgSUtKRSTx9wxwCObmDRUN9HXRj4pKpDLZPIgQrFWBlMIOfBbHZ7GgHMzHU60S7XeC3IEPNDqIA)

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Typescript does not currently support [negated types.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXjpQm) meet your needs?  TS doesn't have negated types and generic conditional types are deferred so such things would only work with non-generic arguments, but you could approximate "not a function" as a union of every primitive plus objects-with-no-`call` plus objects-with-no-`apply`, which gets most things you'd care about.  If that works for your use cases I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me, if you reply)

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If TypeScript had *negated types* of  the sort implemented in (but never merged from) [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) then you could just write

```
// Don't do this, it isn't valid TypeScript:
declare function cloneAnythingButFunction<T extends not Function>(object: T): T;
```

and be done with it.  But there is no `not` in TypeScript, at least as of TypeScript 4.8, so you can't.

---

There are various ways to try to simulate/emulate `not`.  One way is to do what you're doing: write a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that acts like a circular [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which you've done here:

```
declare function cloneAnythingButFunction<T>(object: Exclude<T, Function>): T;
```

This works well for parameters of *specific* types, like

```
cloneAnythingButFunction(123); // okay
cloneAnythingButFunction({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // okay
cloneAnythingButFunction(Test) // error
cloneAnythingButFunction(() => 3) // error
cloneAnythingButFunction(new Test()); // okay
```

but when the parameter is itself of a [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, then it can break down.  And the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) of `this` inside a class method is an implicit generic type parameter.  (That is, it is treated like some unknown type *constrained* to the class instance type).  The compiler doesn't know how to verify assignability of `this` to `Exclude<this, Function>`, which makes sense because the compiler does not know how to say that some subtype of `Test` might not also implement `Function`.

You can work around it by widening `this` to a specific supertype, like `Test`:

```
class Test {
    clone1() {
        const thiz: Test = this;
        return cloneAnythingButFunction(thiz); // okay
        // return type is Test, not this
    }
}
```

---

Another approach to approximating negated types is to carve up the set of all possible types into pieces that *mostly* cover the complement of the thing you're trying to negate.  We know that no primitive types are functions, so we can start with

```
type NotFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | ....
```

And then we can start adding in object types that are also not functions.  Probably any arraylike type will not also be a function:

```
type NotFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | 
   readonly any[] | ...
```

And any object that doesn't have a defined `apply` property is also not a function:

```
type NotFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | 
   readonly any[] | { apply?: never, [k: string]: any } | ...
```

And any object that doesn't have a defined `call` property is also not a function:

```
type NotFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | 
   readonly any[] | { apply?: never, [k: string]: any } | 
   { call?: never, [k: string]: any };
```

Should we keep going or stop there?  The above definition of `NotFunction` will misclassify any objects with both an `apply` property and a `call` property.  Are we worried about those?  Are we likely to run into non-function objects with properties named `apply` and `call`?  If so, we can add more pieces.  Maybe we want to add objects without a `bind` property.  Or objects with `bind`, `call`, and `apply` properties but where each of those properties are themselves primitives, like `{ call: string | number | ... , apply: string | number | ... }`...  But at some point we should just stop.  Approximating  by 3.14 is good enough for lots of use cases, and it's usually more trouble than it's worth to approximate it by 3.141592653589793238462643383.  Let's just use the above definition.

Anyway, now let's try to use `NotFunction` in place of `not Function`:

```
declare function cloneAnythingButFunction<T extends NotFunction>(object: T): T;

cloneAnythingButFunction(123); // okay
cloneAnythingButFunction({ a: 1, b: 2 });
cloneAnythingButFunction(Test) // error
cloneAnythingButFunction(() => 3) // error
cloneAnythingButFunction(new Test()); // okay    

class Test {
    clone1() {
        return cloneAnythingButFunction(this); // okay
    }
}
```

Those behave as desired.  It's still *possible* that some subtype of `Test` could be assignable to `Function`, but the compiler doesn't care and neither do we, I think.

And of course we don't care about this:

```
cloneAnythingButFunction({apply: "today", call: "1-800-TYP-SCRP"}); // error oh noez
```

because if we did we'd have to add some more digits of  to our approximation of `NotFunction` to deal with it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxCwICcCW8kG8AoQpUpAMwFdh4AXbAe2CXgBsmIBBYAT1oAtswAOYAhSrQBi1Oo2AAeACoA+ABQMARgCsIdAFxIAogA82lACYQlAGiTSa9JsoCUBxQRJkvmCLUqZmKFpMSjp-CHMAYXYMdW1dWmdPUgBfYi82ECgoJEVoWg8vDJiIAEZVZ0Ki6vgmIKQBbAAvN3ykAF4GwSgAbmTqsh8-AJYS7j5BEXEpGUdgVUam5x6kAHpVpAYAaxAefoG1jaH-ZloeGGRsHLyg22AGAsaofbI0rzT+tg5xxqmJe1kTFUpQATABmZaHTY7PbFb68X5if6zOSqfBIEAGUq2DQGEFIFKQ9bQ3afMYIyZImYOVE3RJQrCYBiYMnwiZCKkAuaqCodZRICEMzBMllwjA-SnTLmojAAd1y+QqRI221JhA+oEgsAQyE4MBgTOMVVIZwuSAAcg9pUwOkggjgREgAD5IYCUMAaLDOpAaBgMVgQEDMF1u1isb3USzkIQRb0abDCIQFF0+EDmJisHgY3gAbQAus7+uiQPrMwB+AwYABuWFsOa2BntHLzBiDWZS3vR8BAYYrrogNcwdYbduCzdbvAJL2JnZ9QnMfertaQ9cbY5ELez7e9BAxpZ4Bkt1MBwBx87XDuE3rdHq9Lt9-sDwddlDDEeAUZj5jjCaT3tT6bAJmW75rY3ZhoeVoojaKR9P0VA0jaXzihSHJStBCjuBAxi0Og5g5Ee1rAGomg6PouSuLkxpFMcIz2qEwwRNEHBxGRiT9B8xRZNcbREAcyFlLyfEHIMvgnKMbKIuhiHzE8SQHG8rzpGQAkSmhyIycC4LKiSsIqeS7J-Me3LFliOJ4gSOmqnppCqahRlEaodKVMSjLMqyKGGZyGE8pU7T8oKrnCu5YpcPZ3maXKCpBEqKzEtZym2QZUkaSeaJ7jAmYGAARLQDDmLs2VgT2rA5aUAC0AAcAAM1XlYoACaAAK5UAMqRAASk12WWXFGxuZgmz8K6DAQE0xApEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the following:

```
type ExcludeFunction<T> = T extends Function ? never : T
```

Usage:

```
function cloneAnythingButFunction<T>(value: ExcludeFunction<T>) { ... }
```

Which will cause the following message if a `Function` type was passed (or not removed from a union):

`TS2345: Argument of type  T  is not assignable to parameter of type  ExcludeFunction<T>`

Comment: Not to be harsh, but this and its shortcomings are described in the second paragraph of @jcalz's answer. (Your `ExcludeFunction<T>` is pretty much equivalent to `Exclude<T, Function>`.)

Comment: Not at all - I must have missed that! Always happy to learn :)