# object type that can't be assigned an array

Tags: typescript

What TypeScript type can be assigned plain objects but not arrays?

```js
type PlainObject = Record<string, any>; // doesn't pass all tests :(

function test(a: PlainObject) {};

// ok
test({});
test({ a: 1, b: null, c: [2, 3] });

// should error
test(1);
test(null);
test([]);
test([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WokKpW) to prohibit anything with a known `indexOf` property, which will end up accepting most non-array objects (including `new Object()`), but isn't a perfect match (as it will reject some acceptable values).  Without a description of your use case I'm not sure how to advise.

Comment: (This is a duplicate in spirit of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73940068/2887218) which asks about "non-`Function`s" instead of "non-`Array`s", but hits the same issues.)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, sorry, `new Object()` was a typo. Removed now. The use case is to implement a `shallowEquals` function that accepts either 2 objects or 2 arrays, but not 1 object and 1 array.

Comment: But arrays *are* objects in JavaScript; can you describe what makes an array "not an object" in your opinion?

Comment: I get that arrays are technically objects. I was just hoping that TypeScript could help alert users that try to do something like `shallowEquals([1, 2], {"0": 1, "1": 2}))`. But, looking at this again, maybe this should be allowed. Need to think a bit more about this. Thanks for your response and the `indexOf` suggestion!

Comment: Let me know when you decide what you'd like to see here.