# in typescript, how do I describe the conditional relationship between generic parameters?

Tags: typescript

For a func taking 2 params a and b, I want to achieve this:

when `b` is `number`, a can be anything
when `b` is `string`, a must be `string` as well

so I created 2 func types

```
type F1 = <T>(a: T, b: number) => string
type F2 = (a: string, b: string) => string
```

and try to intersect(overload) them

```
const f: F1 & F2 = (a, b) => ...
```

typescript works correctly when I call it

```
f(3, 3) // ok  
f(true, 3) // ok  
f('3', '3') // ok  
f(3, '3') // error
```

however, typescript considers a, b to be any, so the func definition of `f` has an error

```
const f: F1 & F2 = (a, b) => ... // a and b are any
```

How should I fix this? Or is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want `function foo<T>(a: T, b: number): string;
function foo(a: string, b: string): string;
function foo(a: any, b: string | number): string { return 'bar' }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thnik TypeScript is inferring types `a` and `b` as `any` because it cannot determine its types based on the provided function types `F1` and `F2`.
however you can do this :

```js
type F = <T extends string | number> (a: T extends string ? string : any, b: T ) => string;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UA8AVKEAewIDsAmAzlAcAE4CWOA5lAD5Q4CuAtgEYSkB8UAFAIYAuKGkzZ8REhWpQA-MTKUaQvjhAAaKKyFoAlAm6TFAbgBQJgMYB7HCSgAzIXET8NrPfG4AiT2bs8A3gC+GgDMegD04VCWANYmfmSMEKERUbHxPADkIZka2Zmp0XF++RqJEIU4lsBFUBkheTmV1UVAA)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I just need to change any to unknown to enforce type checking. However, the type guard is still not working, in the b is string branch, a is still inferred as "T extends string ? string : unknown", so I still cannot use string functions on parameter a, 

const f: F = (a, b) => typeof b === 'string' ? a.toLowerCase() : ''

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function Overloading`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
// Fix typescript doesn't have negated type https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196
function f<T>(a: Exclude<T, string>, b: number): string
function f(a: string, b: string): string

function f<T>(a: string | T, b: string | number): string {
    if (typeof a === 'string'){
        return a.toLowerCase()
    }

    return `${a} ${b}`
}

f(3, 3) // ok
f(true, 3) // ok
f('3', '3') // ok
f(3, '3') // error
f('a', 1) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEEsA9QFwJ4AcCmBnAxgJ0kuoATAe3QDsByfACwEMA3FUUlAcxrhQPmUarjiRoAXCBaQ4VAK4AjAHQYiAW2CLI2ImiIAzOMAAqPAMrZcuyGjST0wACwBGAJwA2AFBbJpDHEhFSoLQA8egB8ABQ0QqAAotAYADaSBChBADSgaHA4pCzBadKRpJKK0ihYAJSRGVksbh5ePn5a4ZWZkNl5LdUV6a3ZLrWe3r7+QWERPdWgAD6geh0TbSzTTEUl5Z2LoADeLqB7oJBaoKGIqNqgNKAAvDeg5FWL5GU7+6+gWChwklh+NLJwRAAMkQAO6lADCNDQKFCZV2+wAvv1Xh8vj9QAADAAkWxoCNAOOkCIxLiRblCAGY0hSyqAQKAiABrcmZKzU2n0pnk8gU8hpHlPOlgLlNKl3XkcsClLBELDcmh80B2SWgaWyoA)

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73941949/14813577

Comment: This is the correct answer. I accepted Hatana's answer since it is using the arrow function syntax. However, in both answers, the type guard is still not working, in the b is string branch, a is still inferred as T | string, so I still cannot use string functions on parameter a,

function f<T>(a: T | string , b: number | string) { return typeof b === 'string' ? a.toLowerCase() : '' }

Comment: You cannot use string function because it's possible to pass `a` as number and `number.toLowerCase()` will throw error.

Comment: Typescript cannot infer if `b` is string then `a` is string because typescript is compile time type check and doesn't know how the function is called.

Comment: Typescript doesn't know how the function is called, but knows all the possible ways a function can be called and should be able to type check each case, that's what Type Guard is for. E.g., const f = (x: number | string) => typeof x === 'string' ? x.toLowerCase() : '', here x.toLowerCase() is allowed since in that branch TypeScript knows x is a string. I guess right now the Type Guard only "guard" the variable being checked against, but do not look further on constraints on related variables, but in theory, it should be able to, otherwise it kinda defeated the purpose of function overloading

Comment: you demonstrated yourself f(3, '3') is error, which means TypeScript CAN infer if b is string then a is string

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916#issuecomment-562148122, someone is talking about the exact same issue there, the best workaround is wrap the 2 params into an object and type guard the whole object

Comment: So you want to infer if `b` === 'string'. then a is string. Like `typeof b === 'string' ? a.toLowerCase() : null` doesn't error?

Comment: that's correct.